# Dependency injection in CodeIgniter's controller for easier unit testing

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, dependency-injection, phpunit

I am trying to make PHPUnit and CodeIgniter cooperate. The problem is that I have no idea how to use DI in the controller.
e.g.:

```
//Non-viewing method called in the form when user click "register" button on the registration view.
public function register(){
    //fetchInput is a private method returning an array of wanted data fetched from user input. 
    $insertData = $this->fetchInput_register();
    $insertData["permissions"] = "guest";

    $this->load->model("Users_model");
    $this->Users_model->insert($insertData);
    redirect("signing");
}
```

And here is the problem. This method loads the Users_model. Because this is a controller we are supposed to use such methods as "load". But this method loads the whole new part of the code.

How am I supposed to unit test this method? I can't use Users_model because it mediates with a database. Should I mock the Users_model? But then I should mock the load method too. I have a feeling that I am doing this in a very wrong way.

P.S. This method is error unfriendly, I know that.

Comment: Don't know if this would work, but here's a git [integrating phpunit with CI.](https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test) And it was updated recently.

Comment: See also, https://github.com/fmalk/codeigniter-phpunit which doesn't rely on netbeans and explains fairly well the hacks to make CI3 phpunit friendly. Hasn't been updated recently though.